# Reference request: Lipid composition in bacterial, yeast and human membranes

Tags: cell-membrane, literature, lipids

I would like to know about the lipid composition of different kinds of cellular membranes. I remember going through such a table once in a paper, but I am unable to find it anymore. What I am looking for is a kind of tabular data which shows the percentage of phosphocholines, cholesterol, sphingolipids and other kinds of lipids organism-wise (and if possible tissue/organ/organelle wise wherever applicable).

So please share the papers/links/books etc where I may find this information. Thank you.